# Major problems with images

Tags: html, image

I tried everything but images just will not show.  I open a new folder and inside have two folders one named images and the other named index.html. I put one image in the image folder and do a basic HTML code (see example) but yet never get the image on screen. I have checked each and every key stroke and made sure all file names are all lower case and have the right file extensions:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> cakes.co.uk </title>
</head>

<body>
<figure>
<img src="images/cakes.jpg" alt="a sponge cake" height="200" width="400">
<figcaption> a well prepared cake </figcaption>
</figure>


</body>

<footer>
</footer>

</html>
```

There is nothing else in the new folder that I create and have on the desktop. I have just my image folder and my index folder. All fig captions and alt code works but I only get a little symbol in top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

The error is the image path `src="images/cakes.jpg"`.

To fix the path, use either `src="cakes.jpg"` or give full absolute path of the image.

Answer (score 0):

If the 'images' folder is in the same folder as index.html, your code should work properly. However, please remember the spelling of the folders and files should be exactly same as it is in your path (Also check for capital and simple letters).

If your index.html is in a different folder, you must go back a file and then access the images folder. For example:

```
<img src="./images/cakes.jpg" alt="a sponge cake" height="200" width="400">
```

Answer (score 0):

One of two problems:

**1.** Your URL might be wrong. If your index.html file is in a parent directory and your image is in /images, then `src="images/cakes.jpg"` is correct. But if index.html is in /index and the image is in /images, then you need to change your link to the **parent directory** selector: `..` like so: `src="../images/cakes.jpg"`.

**2.** Your folder does not have the right **permissions set**. Check that they're something like 755 and the user www-data has read access to them.